# Problem when Date add and subtract Feb month

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I have from and to date calendar, I have to show the Last one month period either selected start or end date. I am using moment to add 1 month when start entered to get max date, same subtract one month when end date entered first to get min date.  The problem is Feb month,  when I enter end date March 28,29,30 2021 and subtract 1 month using moment always return 28/02/2021.

Answer (score 0):

You are subtracting a month and the last day of February is the 28th. It will only begin to return a lower day when it is less than March 28th.

Comment: Thanks Javier, But when I subtract by  30 days, again I have problem of Feb month, suppose If I select Jan 31 start date, it lead to Mar 2 as end date. but it crossed more than a month, instead of it suppose to show end date as 28 Feb.